# Исключение на переполнение txt-файла

Tags: c#, исключения

Как поймать исключение на переполнение файла txt в с#?
Я ввожу информацию в файл и хочу обезопасить себя от ситуации, когда память в файле кончится. В java вроде - `catch ( EOFException e);`, а в с#? `catch (IOException e)` - это просто на ввод вывод.

Comment: Вы считываете информацию из файла и это исключение выбрасывается при достижении конца файла?

Comment: Речь идет о записи в файл. Что такое "память в файле" по-Вашему?

Answer (score 1):

Исключение  [EndOfStreamException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.endofstreamexception.aspx) выбрасывается при достижении конца файла (потока).

Comment: Исключение, которое создается при попытке выполнить **чтение** за пределами потока.

IMHO автор **пишет** в файл.